# Is it possible to call sql server query in cake php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp

Cake php version 2.5.1. I need to execute query for sql server using cakephp, i'm not sure why it will shows the error "Undefined variable: result" in button function.Thanks in advance for any answer.

this is the function in controller (uploadscontroller)

```
public function create_ajax_01($ct_no = null, $result = null) {

    $result = $this->query("EXEC qas.dbo.batchload;");}
```

and the button function (upload.ctp)

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Run', array('options' => $result, 'label' => false, 'error' => false,'id' => 'ct_no'));
```

Button ajax function:

```
$('#ajax_result01').on('change', '#result', function() {
        result = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://' + hostname + '/' + appname + '/qas/uploads/create_ajax_01/' + ct_no,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ajax_result01').html(data);
        },
        });
    });
```

SQL Server Query:

```
EXEC qas.dbo.batchload
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $this->$model->query("EXEC qas.dbo.batchload;");}
```

Where `$model` should be replaced by your model name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, i've try this out before but it won't work. Any other solution? Thank you!